# How to run Kaltura open source project (Java)

Tags: java, kaltura

I got Kaltura java source from [here](http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testme/client-libs.php). I have attempted to run this code in eclipse but received some errors. The main question is how could I compile this code to get output. The errors are presented below.

> Generated KS locally: [NTk1MmUyNTgxMmU0ODhiOWZhMDgzOTBhOGNlYTA4NThlMmU3OTMxZXw1NDMyMTs1NDMyMTsxMzk4MjI1NTEzOzI7Nzk1Mzt0ZXN0VXNlcjs=]
>   Example failed.
>   com.kaltura.client.KalturaApiException: Invalid KS "NTk1MmUyNTgxMmU0ODhiOWZhMDgzOTBhOGNlYTA4NThlMmU3OTMxZXw1NDMyMTs1NDMyMTsxMzk4MjI1NTEzOzI7Nzk1Mzt0ZXN0VXNlcjs=", Error "-1,INVALID_STR"
>       at com.kaltura.client.KalturaClientBase.getExceptionOnAPIError(KalturaClientBase.java:617)
>       at com.kaltura.client.KalturaClientBase.throwExceptionOnAPIError(KalturaClientBase.java:621)
>       at com.kaltura.client.KalturaClientBase.doQueue(KalturaClientBase.java:274)
>       at com.kaltura.client.services.KalturaMediaService.list(KalturaMediaService.java:316)
>       at com.kaltura.client.services.KalturaMediaService.list(KalturaMediaService.java:305)
>       at com.kaltura.client.services.KalturaMediaService.list(KalturaMediaService.java:301)
>       at Kaltura.list(Kaltura.java:115)
>       at Kaltura.main(Kaltura.java:60)

Answer (score 1):

I guess It's happened because you're set Request URL to http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/index.php?service=media&action=list which is returned XML below.

```
<xml>
    <result>
        <error>
            <objectType>KalturaAPIException</objectType>
            <code>SERVICE_FORBIDDEN</code>
            <message>The access to service [media->list] is forbidden</message>
            <args>
                <item>
                    <objectType>KalturaAPIExceptionArg</objectType>
                    <name>SERVICE</name>
                    <value>media->list</value>
                </item>
            </args>
        </error>
    </result>
    <executionTime>0.021459817886353</executionTime>
</xml>
```

Not GZIP value.